# ReactiveCocoa and UISwitch

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiswitch, reactive-cocoa

```
//@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
//@property (nonatomic) UIImage *image;
//@property (nonatomic) PhotoEffect *effect;
//@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *glossSwitch;
```

Currently, I have a problem due to `UISwitch` doesn't work with `KVO`. The code below triggers only if switch was changed from its initial state:

```
RAC(self.imageView, image) = [[[[RACSignal

                                combineLatest:@[ RACObserve(self, image), [self.glossSwitch
                                                                                   rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged], RACObserve(self, effect)]]
                              deliverOn:[RACScheduler scheduler]]
                              reduceEach:^UIImage *(UIImage *im, UISwitch *glossSwitch, PhotoEffect *effect) {
                                  if (!im) {
                                      return nil;
                                  }
                                  if (effect) {
                                      im = [im imageWithEffect:effect.type];
                                  }

                                  if (glossSwitch.on) {
                                      im = [GlossyIcon applyShineToImage:im];
                                  }
                                  return im;
                              }]
                              deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler];
```

Comment: Sorry about my (since deleted) answer. Poor reading comprehension on my part.

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers No problem :) We all do that time to time.

Answer (score 1):

`-combineLatest:` accumulates one "next" item from each signal in the array until all the signals have sent one. At that point, it finally sends a `RACTuple` containing the "next" value from each signal in the array.

Your `RACObserve` signals send one "next" each upon initial setup. They'll send "next"s again in the future when the properties change.

The `UISwitch` is sending a "next" as expected based on the control event.  But since the `RACObserve` signals have likely stopped sending "next"s, they leave your `UISwitch` hanging and `-combineLatest:` can't send more than that first "next".  So your `-reduceEach:` only fires that first time.

EDIT:  Actually, hang on - I just reread the docs for `-combineLatest:` and it says that once the first full set of "next"s are provided (for each signal), any additional "next"s from any signal should cause the combined signal to pass a `RACTuple` with the latest values from each.  So I'm not exactly sure what's going on, sorry for the non-answer!

Comment: Thanks, I got it. 
I declared boolean value, made toggle method to change it each time UISwitch changes and started to observe it with RACObserve. And RACObserve don't send a signal, when boolean property changes. I checked with KVO (added observer) and it works. Do you know what's wrong with RACObserve?

Comment: When you change the property, make sure to change it via the object specified in the `RACObserve`, instead of using "_" ivar access on self for example. Should work.